# How to integrate an Adyen Native 3DS2 component into a custom form using React & TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, adyen

When building your own payment form, the [Adyen documentation](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/3d-secure/native-3ds2/web-component/?tab=create-new-component_2) mentions making use of the `onAdditionalDetails` property as part of a configuration object. The example they use is:

```js
function handleOnAdditionalDetails(state, component) {
  state.data // Provides the data that you must pass in the `/payments/details` call.
  component // Provides the active component instance that called this event.
}
```

Is this correct? In the `.d.ts` file, the type for state object is stated as `any`.

Also, the 5th point of `Step 3: Handle the 3D Secure 2 action` states that:

> 5. Get the state.data from the onAdditionalDetails event, and pass it your server.

As I'm building the card component using React, does this mean `state.data` needs to be passed in as the payload?

There isn't an example that I've found for this scenario. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the `onAdditionalDetails` handler you can grab the `state.data` (you are correct) and you send that to Adyen with the `/payments/details` API call. This contains the details of the threeDSResult result:

```
{
  "details": {
   "threeDSResult": "eyJ0cmdssdsdsds="
  }
}
```

It is a little bit easier when using the Adyen Javascript API, as there is a method that you can use to perform this step (`paymentsAPI.paymentsDetails({ details: PaymentCompletionDetails }`.

Checkout the [Adyen Node 3DS2 example](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-node-online-payments/tree/main/3ds2-example).

Comment: The Node 3DS2 example is for the backend, so I'm not sure if it will suit my use case. Where would state come from `onAdditionalDetails`? Also, if I was making a POST request to the `/payments/details` endpoint, what would you suggest to retrieve `state.details` in a React application?

Comment: The `onAdditionalDetails` handler receives `state` as parameter: `const onAdditionalDetails = async (state, component)`. You can see this in the GitHub sample in the frontend folder. Ideally you pass this to the backend that will perform the `/payments/details` call. You could do the API call from the frontend (from the handler possibly) but must then address/prevent the CORS error.